# I have got problems with nginx http autorisation

Tags: php, nginx, .htpasswd

I take project from job to home with all of their configuration and with htpasswd.pwd file.
At job all works great, at home i see internal 500 error.

In logs I have got this:

```
2014/08/03 21:06:53 [crit] 8543#0: *15 open() "/etc/nginx/htpasswd.pwd" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: mylocal.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "mylocal.dev"
```

and here is my `namei -l` result:

```
root@laptop:/home/root# namei -l /etc/nginx/htpasswd.pwd 
f: /etc/nginx/htpasswd.pwd
drwxr-xr-x root    root    /
drwxr-xr-x root    root    etc
drw-r--r-- myuser  myuser nginx
-rwxr-xr-x myuser  myuser htpasswd.pwd
```

what i must to do?

Comment: who should be the owner of htpasswd.pwd?Change it with chown

Answer (score 2):

Set chmod of htpasswd.pwd to 0755, if this doesn't work set it to 0777.

Comment: tryed and restart ngnx - the same problem.

Comment: chmod +x to nginx folder solve it. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @butteff please mark the question as solved, either by marking this answer or posting your own explaining what you did, don't keep the question open.